# Consultas Condicionales a BBDD

Tags: javascript, python, flask

me encuentro desarrollando una app web en Flask implementando AJAX

Hasta ahora logre filtrar una tabla con datos de un solo desplegable

Mi consulta es : como se generaria una consulta condicional ej :
el usuario selecciona 1 filtro  de año x ej

**mi query quedaria : select * from tabla where año= {seleccion del usuario}**

lo que necesitaria agregar serian nuevos desplegables x ejemplo tipoproducto

y si el usuario selecciona el año y el tipoproducto

**mi query quedaria : select * from tabla where año= {año} and tipoproducto={tipoproducto}**

Me imagine armar algo como guardar los valores en una lista desde los forms luego recorrerla y generar la consulta appendando los valores como strings , pero no se si es como se hace realmente

No pegue mi codigo porque con alguna respuesta o ayuda con pseudocodigo ya me alcanzaria , yo despues lo adapto 
Pero si es necesario lo comparto aqui

Busque en preguntas anteriores y no pude encontrar exactamente lo que necesito , si existe una respuesta a esto y lo quieren compartir con gusto la revisare

Muchas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una lista donde vayas agregando los filtros que correspondan y, al final, la unes en una cadena que vas a agregar a tu query:

```
lista = []

# Cambia la condición por lo que recibes en POST o GET
# para saber si debes filtrar por año
if 1 == 1
    lista.append("año = {año}")

# Cambia la condición por lo que recibes en POST o GET
# para saber si debes filtrar por tipo producto
if 1 == 1
    lista.append("tipoproducto = {tipoproducto}")

# Definir cómo se van a unir los elementos de la lista
s = " AND "

# unir elementos de la lista con " AND " y guardarlo en conds 
conds = s.join(lista)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte , lo voy a probar , al final tenia que confiar un poco mas en mi instinto